# Left side is a treeview menu and right side need to be the content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC5 razor project and I have a cshtml divided into two parts, left part has a div with a treeview with options like a menu and the right part is a div that I would like to load cshtml that correspond to the option selected in treeview, ¿how can I do to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Create shared partial view that contain the tree view and load it on your _Layout page. If you need more details let me know

Comment: Please, let me know details. Main idea is when I click on a node on left part that has a page url to be load, such url (cshtml) must be loaded on right part.

Comment: Please consider this as similar to frameset since you can target a html page to be loaded in a specific frame

Comment: Yes you can do it. Yes you can do it imagine you have  tree view on left side each tree node should have to carry the actionLink with the necessary parameters to load the view from the controller which you calling. 

And then you can use load it to specific div

Comment: can you Post your code what you tired so far

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that this is a simple navigation that is consistent amongst all pages, for which you can put the common navigation in the `_Layout.cshtml`.  This file contains all the common , ,  tags used for each page.  If you put your navigation in here then it will also be displayed on each page.

The navigation options can then link to your normal actions which display the corresponding views within the layout page.

In this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) the author discusses adding a simple navigation (in the section "Using a Layout for common site elements") in the _Layout with the difference that the navigation is at the top and not at the side.  You can use `css` to style the page differently.

Comment: It would mean that page which reference the common layout (this last which contains navigation treeview and is left part) has to be known and loaded first but my case is different because when you click on a treeview node is when you know url to be loaded then in right part. ¿Am I misunderstanding your solution?

Comment: similar to frameset since you can target a html page to be loaded in a specific frame